# ERROr: **npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI...'**

Tags: npm

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPUJK.jpg) I am cloning the `sitecore Habitat` project to my local machine.
After cloning while running `npm install`, I am getting this error. I tired in all possible ways from the stack overflow answers, but did not succeed with answers still its showing errors, if anyone known about this please let me know.

```
ERROr: **npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI...'**
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your error log file given on the second last line of your image stack trace?

Comment: What do you see when you directly access the registry? -> `http://registry.npmjs.org`

Answer (score 34):

Just delete

> package-lock.json  file

It works for me.

I getting error like:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

I found this solution in another question and worked for me after I set the registry like this:

`npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: So What does this actually do? @luis

Comment: It tells node where to look for the packages, in that case the mirror server is located under the address `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: You mean `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` ?

Answer (score 6):

Setting npm Registery worked for me

npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Please focus on the difference and additional insight your post provides when compared to the much older posts, like the one by Luis Febro. Try to aoivd the impression that you simply copy existing answers with less appropriate formatting...

Answer (score 4):

This error means there is a proxy in the middle which is denying you access to the Internet.

The error comes from the HTML page that is rendered from the proxy.

You need to check with your network administration to either allow the connection through (an exception), or you have to configure the variable `HTTP_PROXY` in your environment, which is like this:

`http://username:password@proxy.server.com:port`

Comment: but i am using direct access, no proxy server

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).

Comment: @SHREE show your npm config pls,.. Burhan's explanation is the only one that makes sense. You should receive JSON but you don't, so there is something in between which denies the JSON but sends you an error message in HTML instead.

Comment: how to attach the file here ? any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Having tested `npm install` in several repos with the same error I ran `npm cache clean --force` and tried again. This is not as severe a solution as deleting all traces of node and reinstalling from the ground up.

I use an npm registry hosted at work for internal npm packages so couldn't change the registry source.

Answer (score 1):

**yes , its happned due to proxy setting, if this problem occurs, please check your proxy setting, in my case npm was getting blocked, You need to check with your network administration to either allow the connection through (an exception), or you have to configure the variable HTTP_PROXY in your environment**

Answer (score 1):

You need to check all required npm config setup like:

```
https-proxy=https://username:password@accessdomain:port/
proxy=http://username:password@accessdomain:port
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//If required also add
msbuild_path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. I had un-installed NodeJs and deleted folders npm and npm-cache from Users\username\Appdata\Roaming folder and installed it.

Then set config registry by using command terminal as.

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

To give an actual description of the problem and solution:

This happens when the URL set as your npm registry is incorrect (or as others have mentioned, a proxy has got in the way). Either way, you end up trying to download a package from an endpoint displaying HTML, which `npm` fails to parse as JSON (as one would expect).

You can view the URL for your npm config with
`npm config get registry`, and set it with `npm config set registry https://my.registry.com/` (or `https://registry.npmjs.org/` for the public registry)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentioned here. Nothing worked. Then I moved jsonwebtoken dependency to the bottom of package.json ( Below my registy specific dependencies ).

**Then it worked!**

Spent 6 hours in fixing this. I feel so small now.